# Proper way to findOne document in Template Event?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to findOne document in my Template.admin.events code. I have a form and onClick I want to verify if the ID of the ObjectID entered is an existing document in my collection and fetch that result to show it on the template.

My event code on the client :

```
Template.admin.events({
    'click #btnAjouterObjet'(event) {
            let objetIdInput = $('#object_id').val().toString();
            Meteor.subscribe('objetsFindOne', objetIdInput, {
                onReady: function () {
                    let obj = Objets.findOne();
                    if (obj) {
                        console.log("found");
                        console.log(obj);
                        objetsArr.push(objetIdInput);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("not found");
                        console.log(obj);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
});
```

In my Objets api :

```
Meteor.publish('objetsFindOne', function objetsFindOne(param_id){
    return Objets.find({_id : param_id});
  })
```

I have verified and my objetIdInput always change on click when a different Id is entered but the subscribe always returns the first id entered. I also added the onReady because otherwise it returned undefined.

I am new to Meteor and I have also tried to subscribe to all the collection and doing the find on the client but I don't think it is the best idea as my collection has about 22000 documents.

Comment: The subscribtion takes some time but I can't figure out how to wait for it to be ready before executing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate a little bit on the first answer, as to how to change this pattern:

(1) you should place your `Meteor.subscribe()` call in your `Template.admin.onCreated()` function.

(2) the subscription reads from a reactive value, for example, `new ReactiveVar()`.

(3) now, anytime the reactive value changes, the subscription will re-run. So, in your template event, you set the reactive value to the id and let the subscription handle the rest.

Discover Meteor and other resources should be helpful on any details.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this all wrong. I suggest you take a look at [Template-Level Subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/)

Answer (score 0):

I opted for the use of a method :

Client side:

```
'click #btnAjouterObjet'(event) {
        let objetIdInput = $('#object_id').val().toString();
        let result = Meteor.call('findObj', objetIdInput, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.reason);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
```

On the server side :

```
 Meteor.methods({
findObj: function (param_id) {
      console.log(Objets.find({ _id: param_id }).fetch());
      return Objets.find({ _id: param_id }).fetch();
    },
});
```

Comment: That's a very non-meteoric way to approach this problem in that you've bypassed reactivity, @Jeremy S has the correct solution.

Comment: You were right. I did not understand the concept of Reactivity in meteor until this problem. ReactiveVar is def the way to go!